# Enable anonymous access to ADFS 2.0 SharePoint site

Tags: 2007

I have a SharePoint 2007 portal configured to authenticate againsts a STS (ADFS 2.0) using the FormsSignIn (Forms Authentication on the ADFS). Is there any way to have a few pages living in the SharePoint portal that allow anonymous access? I've tried checking the "Enable Anonymous Access" in the SharePoint Central Admin, and I've tried adding location sections in the web.config, but both of these still redirects to the ADFS login page.

I have re-branded the ADFS login site so it looks less generic and more like our SharePoint login page. Should I just move those anonymous access pages out of SharePoint and into the ADFS site?

ADFS is new to me and I'm not sure what the best practices are for customizing the login process.

Thanks,

P.S. If someone with enough experience points could add either ADFS, or ADFS-2.0 as a tag, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have configured permissions for anonymous access on the Site Collection/Sites as well. You'll do this under Site Settings > Site Permissions.

Comment: This is set correctly.  It looks like ADFS is even blocking the /_LAYOUTS/ folder.

Comment: ADFS should not block anything. Make sure once again that your web app has allowed anonymous requests and that you have allowed anonymous users access to the site coll/sites

Comment: You're correct.  Before I ran SharePoint's Federation Utility wizard, I did have these settings set correctly. But the wizard disables anonymous authentication. The "Anonymous Access" menu item didn't even show up on the Advanced settings, until I went back and re-enabled anonymous access.  Thanks for the help.